# Shift Indented Code to the Left, Remove leading tabs

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext2

Let's say I have a block of code that is copied from one file to a new blank file. The code from the original file is indented as it should be, however I want to un-indent the code when placed in a new blank file. However, I only want to un-indent to the base indention, meaning I don't want to remove ALL indentations. Make sense?

For example, when pasting a code block into a newly created file, it might look like this:

```
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <div>
            <p>This is a nested paragraph</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Even deeper!</li>
            </lu>
        </div>
```

I'm wanting to create a function, with regex and/or python, that will take the text above and turn it into this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<div>
    <p>This is a nested paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Even deeper!</li>
    </lu>
</div>
```

The only difference is the lead indentation.

Any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it too much trouble to simply select the lines and hit `shift-tab` a couple of times?

Comment: Are all the indentations represented with `\t`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the `dedent` function in the `textwrap` module: http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent

Comment: You have blown my mind. I knew it had to exist somewhere! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If the input will always be in the format you have provided, you can look how many tabs the first line has and remove that many tabs from that line and any subsequent lines.

Answer (score 2):

Select the text you want to indent and press

1) **ctrl + [** to remove one tab space from beginning of each line and

2) **ctrl + ]** to add one tab in each line's beginning.

Not tested for all versions but works for sublime text 2.

Comment: @RahulSatal Welcome. Please do upvote if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **emacs**, you can delete indentation using the 'box mode' commands. You set the mark and cursor on areas of the file that define the box, then type ctrl-x r k to delete the box. Works like a charm.